# Which is faster in golang for finding intersection of two arrays?

Tags: go, set, intersection

Which is faster in golang for finding intersection of two arrays?

Original can be a very large list, as can target

```
original := []string{"test", "test2", "test3"} // n amount of items

target := map[string]bool{
    "test": true,
    "test2": true,
}

for _, val := range original {
    if target[val] {
        return true
    }
}
```

OR

```
original := []string{"test", "test2", "test3"} // n amount of items
target := []string{"test", "test2"}

for _, i := range original {
    for _, x := range target {
        if i == x {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're comparing 2 slices, to a slice and a map. They're not really comparable, and the result will vary depending on the number of elements. You're also not finding an intersection, just returning true if there is a single match.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350609/how-do-you-time-a-function-in-go-and-return-its-runtime-in-milliseconds

Comment: yes, forgot to mention the obvious, just run the two versions with your data and see which one is faster!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, you are not finding an intersection rather you are finding if a single entity of `original` is present in `target`.  That being said, your first example is `O(N)` because the range is `O(N)` and the map lookup is `O(1)`.  Your second example is `O(N^2)` because of the nested range loops.  Without any benchmarking I can tell you the first method will be far superior time wise (in worst case.)

I benchmarked it just to show.  With 5000 items in original, and 500 in target - running both functions above, and testing with all matching and no matching elements in target:

```
BenchmarkMapLookup             50000         39756 ns/op
BenchmarkNestedRange             300       4508598 ns/op
BenchmarkMapLookupNoMatch      10000        103441 ns/op
BenchmarkNestRangeNoMatch        300       4528756 ns/op
ok      so  7.072s
```

This is the benchmarking code:

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

var letters = []rune("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")

func randSeq(n int) string {
    b := make([]rune, n)
    for i := range b {
        b[i] = letters[rand.Intn(len(letters))]
    }
    return string(b)
}

var (
    original         = []string{}
    target           = []string{}
    targetMap        = map[string]bool{}
    targetNoMatch    = []string{}
    targetMapNoMatch = map[string]bool{}
)

func init() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano())
    numItems := 5000
    for i := 0; i < numItems; i++ {
        original = append(original, randSeq(10))
    }

    i := rand.Intn(numItems)
    if i >= 4500 {
        i = 4499
    }
    stop := i + 500
    for ; i < stop; i++ {
        target = append(target, original[i])
        targetMap[original[i]] = true
        noMatch := randSeq(9)
        targetNoMatch = append(target, noMatch)
        targetMapNoMatch[noMatch] = true
    }

}

func ON(orig []string, tgt map[string]bool) bool {
    for _, val := range orig {
        if tgt[val] {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func ON2(orig, tgt []string) bool {
    for _, i := range orig {
        for _, x := range tgt {
            if i == x {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

func BenchmarkMapLookup(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ON(original, targetMap)
    }
}

func BenchmarkNestedRange(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ON2(original, target)
    }
}

func BenchmarkMapLookupNoMatch(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ON(original, targetMapNoMatch)
    }
}

func BenchmarkNestRangeNoMatch(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        ON2(original, targetNoMatch)
    }
}
```